# TextDrawable - Display color based on a key (email, id)

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-adapter, android-drawable

I have an issue when using [TextDrawable](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable) - I want to display the same color for the same user - `int color2 = generator.getColor("user@gmail.com");`, in my case using the `userId` as a key, but instead what I get is same color for all `userId`'s. I tried this in both ListView and now in RecyclerView, but always the same results - all of my contacts share the same color.

This is the code from my ContactsAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.ContactsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

    holder.userName.setText(contact.getUserName());

    TextDrawable.IBuilder builder = TextDrawable.builder()
            .beginConfig()
            .withBorder(0)
            .toUpperCase()
            .endConfig()
            .round();
    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
    // generate random color
    int color1 = generator.getRandomColor();                                    
    // generate color based on a key (same key returns the same color), useful for list/grid views
    int color2 = generator.getColor(holder.getItemId());
    //int color2 = generator.getColor("user@gmail.com");
    TextDrawable textDrawable = builder.build(contactList.get(position).getUserName().substring(0,1), color2);

    holder.thumbNail.setImageDrawable(textDrawable);
}
```

If I use  `int color2 = generator.getColor(holder.userName);` I get different colors for the same name, and if I use  `int color2 = generator.getColor(holder.getItemId());` I get same colors for every userId.

Comment: have you check color2 and color1 value is valid color code .

Comment: @Chetan When I use color1 I get different colors for each user.

Comment: have you tried with static color codes just for checking that , there may problem exist in your TextDrawable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, when you uncomment `int color2 = generator.getColor("user@gmail.com");` line you expect the same user have the same color, but other users have other colors.

`generator.getColor("some_example_string")` will constantly return the same color for every user in your list. I see you have copy-pasted that from the github and you expect it to work for you. Pay attention to the previous line of the author:

> // generate color based on a key

You have to provide a key, and based on that key a color will be generated. Assuming your user's name may be considered as key, you can perform:

```
generator.getColor(user.getName()); // e.g. "John Doe"
```

Now each time the same color will be generated for `John Doe` and a different color for other users.

Comment: I have updated my question (I have posted it in a hurry, so it was not properly composed). I do use a key - in my case `userId`, but what I get is different colors for the same `userId`. This is the line I use: `int color2 = generator.getColor(holder.getItemId());`

Comment: I have chenged my code to `int color2 = generator.getColor(contact.getUserId());` and it works. Thanks